# Pulling in description from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I apologize in advanced if this has been asked before, but part of my problem is I'm not sure how to ask my question ;).  Here we go!

Newbie SQL programmer (SQL server 2008 R2).  I basically have 3 tables: `rma_header`, `rma_detail` and `code_type`.

I'm doing an inner join between the `rma_header` and `rma_detail` tables to pull all the data about our RMA's.  Everything is love but my problem is that in 2 of the fields (`reason` and `fault`) are codes that are stored in the `code_type` table.  So the data is coming out:

rma# |  reason  |  fault

1234 |   012    |     M

In the `code_type` table they have the `reason` and `fault` codes with a description, for example

code_type    |    code_id    |   code_desc

X         |      012      |     Defective Material

F         |       M       |      Sales

where we have multiple code types for X (being for reasons) and F (being for faults) along with a bunch of other code types that the application uses.

So, I'd like to write a query that contains the data and also will put in the description for the codes, instead of the codes themselves.

Can anyone provide some guidance or links so I can learn how to do this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried.  StackOverflow is not a "can i haz the codz" service.

Comment: Welcome! It's easier to understand what you want, if you show us your actual sql that you use. Consider editing your question and adding that, but as far as I understood what you need is just another join to the `code_type` table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just more joins
It should look something like this assuming there is always an existing reason and fault code.

```
Select * From rma_header h
Inner join rma_detail d on d.HeaderID = h.ID
inner join code_type r On d.ReasonCode = r.CodeId and r.Code_type = 'X'
inner join code_type f On d.FaultCode = f.CodeId and f.Code_type = 'F'
```

The trick is you have to join to code_type twice, once for reasons and once for faults.

If rma_detail reason and fault codes could be null then you want a left outer join e.g.

```
Select * From rma_header h
Inner join rma_detail d on d.HeaderID - h.ID
left join code_type r On d.ReasonCode = r.CodeId and r.Code_type = 'X'
left join code_type f On d.FaultCode = f.CodeId and f.Code_type = 'F'
```

Not much different if you'd have had a reason_codes table and a fault_codes table.

Comment: You have a type-o: `on d.HeaderID - h.ID` should be `on d.HeaderID = h.ID`

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson Thanks so much!  I guess I was making a mountain out of a molehill!

Comment: I had to find this one the hard way as well. I think most tutorials consider it so obvious, they don't bother mentioning it.